# accepts_nested_attributes_for has_many :through Create and delete join model objects, depending on other model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, nested-forms, has-many-through

Here are my models

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :user_roles, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :projects, through: :user_roles
    has_secure_password
end

class UserRole < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :project
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
end

class Project < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :user_roles, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :users, through: :user_roles
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_roles
end
```

Currently I'm trying to figure out a proper way for creating multiple UserRole entries in Project creation form.

UserRole stores user_id, project_id and role.
The actual problem: form input for UserRole is User's email, i.e. I should  find User with such email and if such User exists retrieve his id and save it in UserRole.user_id.

It works just well in console, but not with forms.
I tried to use accepts_nested_attributes_for and nested fields in forms

```
 <%= form_for @project do |f| %>
      # project fields
      <%= f.fields_for :user_roles do |role_f| %>
          # user role fields
          <%= role_f.fields_for :user do |user_f| %>
               # user fields
           <% end %>
       <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

With this form I can easily modify any entries. But can't add or delete properly. Also, this form allows to modify User and that's troublesome.
I'm searching for a way to only create and delete Project's UserRoles while keeping User safe.

I tried to make a virtual attribute - email for UserRole that would be a link to User's actual email attribute, but failed.

The whole situation looks as if I am using wrong approach to this problem. Please, advice.

Comment: forgot to add: Rails version 5.0.2, Ruby ruby 2.3.1p112

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I don't think you can have accepts_nested_attributes for :user in UserRoles, since UserRole is what is nested into User and not the other way round. From what you are describing you don't seem to need that anyway though, except if there are other cases in your business logic, apart from this form.

I would highly suggest you watch this railscast on nested forms. It shows a way to dynamically add and remove nested fields (add or remove a UserRole set of fields)

http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2?autoplay=true

However the user email logic would probably have to be extracted into something else. If I were you I would create an ajax call in the email input field. That call would send the email to the server, the server would try to find any matching users and if it finds some it will return their id-email pairs. Then you display the returned data (email) as a select option in a dropdown. When the user clicks the valid email that was fetched, the form sets the id as the value for that field (user_id field inside user_roles). If no user was found, you return a string that says no user was found with that email or something like that.

If you don't want to fetch the ids, you would have to extract the emails from the params hash in the controller. For each email try to find a user and then you would have to find a way to manage the errors for each one separately in case the user was not found. The first option would give a better user experience for sure.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Saw the video and tried to mimic it in my app but failed due to user email/id problem. You are 100% right about using AJAX calls. Currently I'm working on simplified version of this feature (user_roles controller, and params hash). Definitely will try to refactor it into AJAX calls after I get the controller solution working properly.